# Check if all variables have value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

I have a form that I want to use in a function AFTER it has been filled out completely. At the moment I have several values that I have initiated with a null value

```
 const [customerName, setCustomerName] = useState(null);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(null);
  const [work, setWork] = useState(null);
```

And I want to be able to check if the variables have a value so that I can run my function. Here's what I have.

```
let checkValues = () => {
    if (customerName && address && work && image1 === null) {
      console.log('no')
    }
    else {
      console.log('yeah')
    }
  }
```

I figured this code would only say 'yeah' when all 4 variables have a value, however this code will say 'yeah' when only 1 of the values is assigned it will say 'yeah'.

I'm aware that I am probably using the `&&` operator incorrectly, or I am using it unnecessarily and there's a better way to do it.

Comment: You have to perform each `=== null` comparison explicitly.

Comment: You have to check *each variable* for `=== null` (or put them in an array and use an `all?`-like function, or whatever). I'd suggest some JS tutorials/etc. though; SO isn't the best place to get JS-the-language tutorial-level help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you thought that `&&` bound more strongly than `===`. It doesn't. If all variables hold non-zero values when they are "right", then you can just check truthiness:

```js
let checkValues = () => {
    if (customerName && address && work && image1) {
      console.log('yeah')
    }
    else {
      console.log('no')
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise you have to use

```
    if (customerName !== null && address !== null && work !== null && image1 !== null) {
```

Comment: (It might be helpful to point out to the OP that `if (someString)` will work for some validation requirements like an empty string or `null/undefined` but would be truthy as soon as there's whitespace.)

Comment: It looks like that was my issue. Thanks for the help. I'll mark your answer when I can